# cURL php request with ip and port

Tags: php, curl, request

I would like to develop a script which, at the submit of a form, send a request to an url using ip adress and port in order to send an sms via the gateway configured on my phone.

The url I have

```
$url = "192.168.1.31:43382/send.html?smsto=XXXXXXXXXX&smsbody=test&smstype=sms";
```

And my cURL code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

It works fine localy until I put it on my server.

When I log verbose's value, I get this :

```
 Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
 Trying 192.168.1.31... 
 connect to 192.168.1.31 port 43382 failed: Connection timed out
 Failed to connect to 192.168.1.31 port 43382: Connection timed out
 Closing connection 0
```

I've seen that it could be a firewall issue, so I disabled it but nothing new.

I'm new to cURL, if someone could guide me...

Thanks

Comment: ip addresses `192.168.*` are not routable over the wild internet, they are for private use only ... eg if your `server` is not on your local area network, the address will not be reachable from your server.